# Accessing method transform.Rotate in user-built class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm studying C# and Unity3D with "Learning C# by Developing Games with Unity #D Beginner's Guide" by Terry Norton and I'm blocked with an error.

I'm having trouble with accessing a method **transform.Rotate** via user-built class variable.

Below is the error I get.

> Assets/Code/States/SetupState.cs(26,76): error CS1061: Type
>   `PlayerControl' does not contain a definition for`transfrom' and no
>   extension method `transfrom' of type`PlayerControl' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

***SetupState.cs***, state that tries to access **transform.Rotate** via *PlayerControl type variable controller*.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;
using System.Collections;

namespace Assets.Code.States
{
    public class SetupState : IStateBase
    {
        private StateManager manager;
        private GameObject player;
        private PlayerControl controller;

        public SetupState (StateManager managerRef)
        {
            manager = managerRef;
            if(Application.loadedLevelName != "Scene0")
                Application.LoadLevel("Scene0");

            player = GameObject.Find ("Player");
            controller = player.GetComponent<PlayerControl> ();
        }

        public void StateUpdate ()
        {
            if (!Input.GetButton ("Jump"))
                                controller.transfrom.Rotate (0, controller.setupSpinSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            //above tries to access transform.Rotate via controller
        }

        public void ShowIt ()
        {
            GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 180), "Player Color");

            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (20, 40, 80, 200), "Red"))
                                controller.PickedColor (controller.red);

            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (20, 70, 80, 200), "Blue"))
                controller.PickedColor (controller.blue);

            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (20, 100, 80, 200), "Green"))
                controller.PickedColor (controller.green);

            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (20, 130, 80, 200), "Yellow"))
                controller.PickedColor (controller.yellow);

            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (20, 160, 80, 200), "White"))
                controller.PickedColor (controller.white);

            GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 95, Screen.height - 100, 190, 30),
                       "Hold Spacebar to pause rotation");

            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height - 50, 200, 40),
                            "Click Here or Press 'P' to Play") || Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.P))
                                manager.SwitchState (new PlayStateScene1_1 (manager));
        }
    }
}
```

***PlayerControl.cs***, class definition for *class PlayerControl* obviously.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {
    public float setupSpinSpeed = 50.0f;

    public Color red = Color.red;
    public Color blue = Color.blue;
    public Color green = Color.green;
    public Color yellow = Color.yellow;
    public Color white = Color.white;

    void Start () {
    }

    void Update () {

    }

    public void PickedColor(Color playerColor){
        renderer.material.color = playerColor;
        }
}
```

The book mentions that linking the *script PlayerControl.cs* with a *3D game object* is the only thing I need to do to access **method transform.Rotate** and I did link *PlayerControl.cs* and **game object "Player"** together.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLLtY.png //seems that I can't upload images yet.

I'm not a native speaker in English and the book is Korean translated one so some terms are probably used in inadequate ways, so excuse me for it. And the question is a dumb noob one, but please be a nice helpful chap guys, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PlayerControl script is linked to Player GameObject. So you can access to transform property of Player GameObject by doing:

controller.**gameObject**.transform.Rotate

check in MonoBehaviour documentation gameObject property

Comment: Still doesn't work. Can you check  http://i.imgur.com/0oH9hYs.png for me, see if it's correctly linked? Thx

Comment: I misspelt transform... Dumb me.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the dumb question that haunted me is spelling transform right.

Sorry for the bother of reading guys and thx.